# Infer generic parameter from base class

Tags: typescript

How can I infer `abc` from the base class?

```
class BaseClass<T> {}

class A extends BaseClass<'abc'> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}

// NotAbc is 'unknown'
type NotAbc = A extends BaseClass<infer I> ? I : never
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because generic parameter is not in use:

```
class BaseClass<T> {
    t!: T
}

class A extends BaseClass<'abc'> {
    constructor() {
        super()
    }
}

// Abc is 'abc'
type Abc = A extends BaseClass<infer I> ? I : never
```

Now it works as expected

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFMDC4oB4AqA%20aBvAsAFDQnQAuAhAFzQZEC%20RRokMAgtAgB5kIB2AExjwIyVBDQByMACNgknAWKlgAez4QyAJwCuwMqq0AKAJR4ipS9Ag6ADgmMmLpRoVdEA9B%20hs50AJYw0nKSRGQAnvY%20fgC8Ppw8-EJwiCisaP58AGYO0ACSOAD8%20dA0fAgAbg5AA)